# After Deploy MVC 4 Project with CE 4 Database to Azure -> Error "Access to the database file is not allowed" on Opening Website

Tags: azure

I pulish my ASP.NET MVC 4 Web-Project (SimpleMembershipProvider, EF CF) to Windows Azure via Web-Role to Azure Cloud Services. In my Web-Project I use a CE4 Database (.sdf) Database that is placed under "App_Data".

After the publication Process is finishd and I open my WebSite in a Browser I get the following Error:

> Access to the database file is not allowed. [ 1914,File name =
>   E:\sitesroot\0\App_Data\xyzDb.sdf,SeCreateFile ]
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: Access to
>   the database file is not allowed. [ 1914,File name =
>   E:\sitesroot\0\App_Data\LivescoreDb.sdf,SeCreateFile ]

To get the Site running, I connect my via Remote Desktop to my virtual system on azure and musst 
give the "Network Service" account "Wite Access" to the "E:\sitesroot\0\App_Data" Folder.

My Web.Config connection string:

> name="xyzConnection" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\xyzDb.sdf" 
>   providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"

After that my website runs!

With possebilities I have change that bad behavior.

For Example I was try to change the possion of my Database file in the Project but then I can't found a way to put a relative path to the connection-string.

thx

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this](http://www.bartlannoeye.be/blog/deploying-your-site-with-sql-ce-4.0-to-shared-webhosting-part-2) article could help (see down the bottom).

I think, overall, using a SQL CE database with Azure is not a scenario that gives you good coverage of all cases, e.g:

1. If you end up needing more than one instance of that web role, they will *each* have their own copy of the database so your users will likely see inconsistent behaviour based on which instance they hit
2. If you do another deployment/refresh/restart of your application to Azure, there is no guarantee that the data in your App_Data folder (or any files on the file system, really) will be retained (more likely it will be deleted) so if your users have entered data into the database (via your application), you update the app and they come back they might find all their work missing

So, depending on your use case you may find you take on a fair amount of risk (unless you never update your application code or need more than 1 instance of a web role for your application).

A "better" (in quotes as it can be a relative term or one loaded with meaning) is to use [SQL Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/data-management/) as your cloud database and you could do database development locally using, for example, [SQL Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx) if you don't have access to any other SQL Server version locally. This would overcome the issue of multiple web roles (as your database is independent of any of them) and also if you need to redeploy (or similar) to your web roles as the data is in a separate data store.

**Caveat:** I am not sure how much work you will find it is from SQL CE to another SQL version, however there appears to be defined pathways for that, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716668/migrate-from-sqlce-4-to-sql-server-2008), [here](http://our.componentone.com/2010/08/20/upsizing-to-sql-server-from-sql-server-ce-4-beta/), [here](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-use-exportsqlce-to-migrate-from.html) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg592944.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Mr. Astaykov for that Infomations. Before I've deployed my website to Azure I've make a "downgrade" from LocalDB to SQL CE. 
I've done that with the background that I will save money for a website that maybe nobody will use in the future. 
My Site is more a produktive test as a real produktive Website. Currently I have monthly coast of 14,40$ for the Web- and Worker-Role instance. 
This is more that enough for my privat hobby project.

Comment: Also I will open soon a other question here, of how I can host my website in windows Azure under the free of coast "Web Site" feature insteed of the current "Web role" under "Cloud Services" Azure solution. 
I've install it as Web role because I need to use Signal-R and that throws an exeption if I deploy my site as "normal" "Web Site" in Azure by execution of that line of code: 
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseWindowsAzureServiceBus( "MySecredConnectionStringToServiceBus", 1 );

Comment: Maybe me Site grows to real Produktiv I will make on upgrate to real SQL Server. I think with Entity Framework Code First I can create quickly the DB with tables and realations and copy with a Script that data between that.

--> Back to my first Question :)

Comment: Oh i forgot thank you for your first link. I will try it soon and give a feedback!

Comment: I was try the first link with ..."AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("SQLServerCompactEditionUnderWebHosting", true);" ... Its do not help at deployment to Azure. But thx for your support!